# Creating a service in windows

Tags: windows, windows-services

I want to create a windows service to run an exe on start up.
Actually i am using mongodb.
Every time i need to start the mongod.exe at first to perform all operations.

Please give some suggestions to create a service to start this exe on start up.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far,so you may get soon response from community

Comment: I tried editing in registry setting in services. The service is getting added in the services list.But its giving error like not able to start. error :1053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows service needs to communicate with Windows' service control manager. 
I guess that mongodb does not support this out of the box. 
So you either need to create a small service framework that starts mongodb or you can use something like srvany.exe (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/en-us/).

Service Installation can be done with SC.EXE

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB already runs as a service. Why aren't you [installing it the usual way](http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Windows%20Service.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from this link.

Its working fine.

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service
```